# How to get my buttons & navigation working on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, button, browser, safari

I have recently build my very first portfolio website. I added 2 call2action buttons in css, one submit button in my contact form and navigation. They all work with a javascript function for smooth scroll.

The buttons and navigation are working perfect in chrome and other browsers, but not in Safari.

Is there some Safari issue with javascript, css ... or do I need to add something to my code specifically for safari?

[HTML BUTTONS & NAVIGATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqcKL.png) 
[JavaScript smooth scroll when button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgl4w.png) [CSS buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHaz.png)

Comment: use jQuery for listeners and scroll, https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: one more thing, if you have an holder safari you cannot use arrow function for the listener so use the old one function(){}

Comment: What l1nuxuser says, older safari does not support arrow functions. What version of safari are you testing on?